# How to change the default value (-Any-) of an exposed filter in Drupal Views, when using Hierarchical Select?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've made a view with an exposed filter. This filter is taxonomy based, and I'm using Hierarchical Select as the widget because this taxonomy is deeply nested.

This question is greatly similar to:
[How to change the label of the default value (-Any-) of an exposed filter in Drupal Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668266/how-to-change-the-label-of-the-default-value-any-of-an-exposed-filter-in-dru)

However, the poster of that question was not using HS, and so I cannot use the answers there, specifically this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5975294/443219

Where exactly should I place the '#options' key in the $form array when using hook_form_alter, to make this work? I've tried pasting the relevant line of code blindly in different places throughout the array, but I believe HS works a tad different to FAPI...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a horrible answer to this.

I changed line 402 in sites/all/modules/hierarchical_select/hs_taxonomy_views.module from:

```
$any_label = variable_get('views_exposed_filter_any_label', 'old_any') === 'old_any' ? '<'. t('Any') .'>' : '- '. t('Any') .' -';
```

to

```
$any_label = variable_get('views_exposed_filter_any_label', 'old_any') === 'old_any' ? 'Worldwide' : '- '. t('Any') .' -';
```

This works because: in this site, I need the filter on only view - and nowhere else.

This can never be a general solution because:

1. The unholy sin of hacking the core of a module will haunt me forever because I cannot ever use drush to update this module again.
2. If I ever make another view in this site, and decide to have a hs taxonomy exposed filter, it's "Any" option will be displayed as "Worldwide", even if there is no such context: weird.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can point me in a direction that will allow me to solve this cleanly. But I'm going with my hack for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code any drupal module. this will work.

```
/**
 * hook_views_pre_view
 * @param type $view
 * @param type $display_id
 * @param type $args
 */
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args) {
  if ($view->name == 'VIEW_NAME') {
    $filters = $view->display_handler->get_option('filters');    
    $view->display_handler->override_option('filters', $filters);
  }
}



/**
 * hook__views_pre_build
 * @param type $view
 * @return type
 */
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_build($view) { 
  if ($view->name=='VIEW_NAME') {    
    $view->display['page']->handler->handlers['filter']['filter_field']->value['value'] = 8;
    return $view;
  }     
}
```