# drupal 7 views exposed filters How to replace the word "any" in all filters of a form

Tags: forms, drupal, filter, module, view

i want to replace the word 'Any' by 'Indifferent' in all the dropdown selectors of a view exposed form.

So i used [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10642836/change-default-any-in-drupal-7-exposed-views-dropdown-selector-filter) to build a module called **replaceany** .

```
function replaceany_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'block-views--exp-search_page-page') {
$form['views-exposed-form-search-page-page']['#options']['Any'] = t('Indifferent'); } }
```

views-exposed-form-search-page-page is the id of the form , not the name of a field . is it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had done many errors like taking the form id from  css ( firebug). [this article](http://websmiths.co/blog/very-introduction-drupals-hookformalter#comment-1047) was very helpful for me.
Also i don't know why but the dsm($form_id) doesnt give me the correct form id i needed.i used dsm($form['#id']) instead.
Your silence was another kind of response for me .THANKS FROM A DRUPAL NEWBIE